# Adding to existing JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I need some help about adding items to JList. I work on some "library" kind of project. And I need to add readers to already existing JList. But when I try to add it, JList just resets, removes all the readers and starts adding readers to a new blank JList. But I don't need it to make new list but add it to the already existing one.

I know it's something about creating new model after adding, but i don't know where to fix it.

```
panelHorni = new JPanel();
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    listCtenaru = new JList(listModel);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myjlist.bin");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    listCtenaru = (JList)ois.readObject();

    listScroll = new JScrollPane();
    listScroll.add(listCtenaru);


    listCtenaru.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 417));
    listCtenaru.setBackground(new Color(238,238,238));

    panelHorni.add(listCtenaru);
```

listener

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String jmeno = pole1.getText();
            String prijmeni = pole2.getText();

            listModel.addElement(jmeno +" "+ prijmeni);
            listCtenaru.setModel(listModel);

            pole1.setText("");
            pole2.setText("");
            pole1.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Quit multi-posting questions. I just noticed you other question on the same topic: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html. We don't have time to spend answering the same question twice.

Comment: A very useful library for these kind of things is Glazedlists: http://www.glazedlists.com/ you might want to read up on that first.

Answer (score 1):

```
listModel.addElement(jmeno +" "+ prijmeni);
//listCtenaru.setModel(listModel);
```

There is no need to use the setModel() method if you are trying to update the existing model. The fact that you are trying to do this would seen to indicate you are creating a new model instead of updating the existing model.

See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example that updates the existing model.

Answer (score -1):

The default model of `JList` is `ListModel` you must firstly change it inside the constructor to `DefaultListModel`.
 That solves your problem:

```
private JList list ;
private DefaultListModel model;
public ListModelTest(){//default constructor
//....
list = new JList();
model = new DefaultListModel();
list.setModel(model);
//....
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
 model.addElement("element");
 //....
}
```

Comment: nope, didn't work. Each time i try to add reader to existing JList, it replaces the old one with blank new.